# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clearAsyncValidators') while testing Angular component using Jest

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, ts-jest, angular-test

## I'm testing my components using Jest. While I'm running the test getting error.

Below is my onClickLogin() code block

```
 onClickLogin() {
    if(this.loginForm.valid){
      this.api.getLoginData().subscribe(res=>{
        const user = res.find((a)=>{
          return a.email === this.loginForm.value.email && a.password === this.loginForm.value.password
        });
        if(user){
          this.toastr.success("Login success!!");
          this.loginForm.reset();
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        } else{
          this.toastr.error("Invalid credentials!");
        }
      }, ()=>{
        this.toastr.error("Something went wrong!!");
      });
    } else{
      this.toastr.error("Please enter all required fields to proceed!");
    }
  }
```

I am also using Angular Material UI and form validations, for that I am explicitly disabling the form validations.

Below is my test code block using Jest.

```
it('should navigate to dashboard on clicking login', waitForAsync( () => {
    const button = elLogin.queryAll(By.css('button'));
    loginComponent.loginForm.clearAsyncValidators();
    loginComponent.loginForm.clearValidators();
    loginComponent.loginForm.updateValueAndValidity();
    button[0].nativeElement.click();
    loginFixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      loginFixture.detectChanges();
      expect(location.path()).toBe('/dashboard');
    });
  }));
```

Any help on this?

## I've tried disabling all form validations using like this

```
loginComponent.loginForm.clearAsyncValidators();
loginComponent.loginForm.clearValidators();
loginComponent.loginForm.updateValueAndValidity();
```

Also, Ive tried to set the value for the required fields

```
const email = loginComponent.loginForm.controls['email'].setValue("test@gmail.com");
const password = loginComponent.loginForm.controls['password'].setValue("test");
```

But getting the error like below

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clearAsyncValidators')

 const button = elLogin.queryAll(By.css('button'));
    > 93 |     loginComponent.loginForm.clearAsyncValidators();
         |                              ^
      94 |     loginComponent.loginForm.clearValidators();
      95 |     loginComponent.loginForm.updateValueAndValidity();
      96 |     button[0].nativeElement.click();
```

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`loginComponent.loginForm` is `undefined`. Where is it set in the component (in the ngOnInit, in a method?). You will have to make sure that `loginComponent.loginForm` is defined before accessing `clearAsyncValidators`. Call the `ngOnInit` or method where it is being defined. Before the line where the error is, do `console.log(loginComponent.loginForm);` and see if is undefined or not.